# Jquery .children and .each usage

Tags: jquery

OK, I have been able to get this working using the following:

`$('.jcaption').hover(function() {
     $('.caption', this).stop(false, true).animate({bottom:0},{duration:250, easing: style});
$('.jcaption').hover(function() {
     $('.caption', this).stop(false, true).animate({bottom:-100},{duration:250, easing: style});
})`

using the following html:

div class="photo" img src="" div class="caption" span-caption goes here/span-/div-/div>

The problem that I'm having now is that I have to follow this same HTML structure for each image caption.  Is there a way to consolidate this where I could just list several images under the div class photo instead of having to list each separately?

I'm using this code:

```
$('.photo').hover(function() {
    $(this).children()
        .stop(false,true)
        .animate({bottom:-50},{duration:200, easing: style});
```

to animate an image caption, and want to apply the effect to every image with the class .photo.  As the code currently is, it applies the effect only to the first .photo class, and if any more image captions are added with this class, it just overlaps them on the first one.

Here is the corresponding html:

div class="photo" 
img src=""  div class="caption"  span-caption goes here/span-/div-/div>

Comment: If `.photo` is an image, then it can't have children, so `$(this).children()` should be empty. HTML code please!

Comment: Also, you're missing `});` at the end of your code block above...

Comment: sorry about that, maybe this will help.                          <div class="photo">
<img src="" />   
<div class="caption"><span>caption goes here.</span></div>
</div>

Comment: @user1031508: Maybe you should add that to the question

Comment: If all your images are childs of divs with `class="photo"` you should use `$(".photo > img")` to get at them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$('.photo > img').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(false,true).animate({bottom:-50},{duration:200, easing: style});
    });
});
```

, but there's no need to use each with selectors, unless you want to handle some of the returned elements specifically:

```
$('.photo > img').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(false,true).animate({bottom:-50},{duration:200, easing: style});
});
```

**EDIT:** To clarify, like Šime wrote, drop `children()` since image tags can't have them, and it's probably not what you intended.

**EDIT 2:** Changed to reflect new information provided in comments to original question.

Comment: thanks for your reply, when i remove the .children() the actual image is now being animated.  See the above html I posted, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

[What's the problem?](http://jsfiddle.net/DaVfn/)

All the images animate when you hover over them.

Comment: the initial code was working fine, although would only animate 1 instance of .photo, with overlapping captions.  Upon removing the .children() portion of the code, the actual image animated instead for the caption.

Comment: @user1031508: That _is_ your initial code. What is wrong with it?

Comment: i'm sorry, i must not be explaining myself very well.  The problem is that i am wanting to add an animated caption to all images who are children of the class="photo".  The problem with my initial code is that it is not working on all children, only the first.

Comment: @user1031508: The link in my answer works, yes? All I've done is paste in the code you gave us, plus some CSS I guessed. If mine works and yours doesn't, there's something you're not telling us.